# Composer error in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, composer-php

I am getting another error with composer and i don't know what to do the error is: 
Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI and I have checked in a dos prompt my version of PHP and it has been invoked via the CLI.
please help?

Comment: What operating system? What version of eclipse? The [symfony2 eclipse plugin](http://symfony.dubture.com/)?

Comment: windows7, version of eclipse 4.2.2 and yes it is the symfony2 plugin.

Comment: What version of PHP? Did you download a release from [php.net](http://php.net) or are you using a PHP version provided by some pre-packaged wamp server like xampp ?

Comment: version pf php 5.4.22 and yes i did download the release from the php.net and i do have a confgiured web server as well which is xampp.

Comment: How did you configure your PHP-executable in Eclipse? I suggest you have [PDT](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt) installed right? Do you use the nightly builds? The configuration can be found under `Window | Preferences | PHP | PHP Executables Preferences`. Just to clarify for other users - i think we're talking about the [Composer Plugin for Eclipse](http://composer.dubture.com/). **[pulse00](https://github.com/pulse00)** has split the symfony2 and the composer plugin apart quite a while ago.

Comment: Did you possibly add the **`php-cgi.exe`** instead of **`php.exe`** in the PHP executables section `;)`

Comment: yes i do have the pdt but its for java and i just obtained a php plugin and yes it is a nightly build.and its pointing to the php.exe in the php downloaded from php.net and i have tried changing the path to the php exe in the xampp server and i still get the same error message.

Comment: Eclipse invokes the default provided `php.exe` from the `Executables` section as a separate process. This is most likely not related to xampp or any webserver.

Comment: ok what do you suggest point to the xampp version of php.exe and no i didnt add the php-cg.exe instead of the php.exe :)

Comment: I can't follow you here - what `executable` do you want to use in eclipse in order to run your php command line (cli) scripts ( i.e. to run `composer`) ? the one that you downloaded from php.net or the one that came bundled with xampp ?

Comment: i have tried both and composer doesn't seem to like both of them so which one should i be pointing to?

Comment: Which is ideal for me to be building with from xampp or php.net build?

Comment: I guess your downloaded version from php.net is newer than the one that came with xampp - therefore safer and maybe more performant. i would go for that one.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? If yes please add your findings/final working solution as an answer so that other users can benefit aswell :)

Comment: i have pointed to the php.net version and the error seems to be popping up once project is created.

Comment: the same happens in zend studio as well.